# CSS/html: Trying to use flexbox to have a fixed height container at the bottom of page

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to have fixed height container ( `two` ) to be stuck to the bottom of the page and then have the other container take up the available space (flex-grow) .   This is not giving me the desired effect so I'm not sure what I'm missing

```
<div class="container"> 
  
  <div class="one">One</div>
  
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  
</div> 


.container {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   background: black;
}
.one { 
   flex-grow: 1;
   background: green
}
.two {
    height: 90px;
    background:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Height (%)** is used to define a height relative to parent's height. It depends on parent element height so you also need to set `height:100%` to html/body.

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   background: black;
}
.one { 
   flex-grow: 1;
   background: green
}
.two {
    height: 90px;
    background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  
  <div class="one">One</div>
  
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your block is limited to the place it occupies. You have to use the entire viewport in this case. Add this in your CSS :

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that would help is `height:100vh`. Apart from that, to avoid scrollbar, you'll need to remove default margin and padding from html & body.

The `vh` unit is pretty convenient when you want the container tag to fill the available screen space **without introducing vertical scrollbar.**

```css
        html,
        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .container {
          height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          background: black;
        }
        .one {
          flex-grow: 1;
          background: green;
        }
        .two {
          height: 90px;
          background: pink;
        }
```

```html
        <html>

        <body>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="one">One</div>
            <div class="two">Two</div>
          </div>
        </body>

        </html>
```